# Energy flow through string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

When you pull a sled, chemical energy in your body is converted to mechanical energy and heat at the sled. But can we say that there is an energy flow through the string?

[image: Man pulling a sled with a child]

Answer (score 0):

The string transmits the force the man exerts on the sled and the equal and opposite force the sled exerts on the man per Newton's 3rd law.

Since no macroscopic objects, including the string, are ideal rigid bodies, the string will stretch. When it does, some elastic potential energy will be stored in the string due to the work done stretching the string, like a spring. In that sense energy flows *into* the string due to the work done in stretching the string. It will also generate heat due to internal friction work. In that sense energy flows out of the string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My question was rather about the energy that is transmitted to the sled. Can that be said to flow through the string or can we only say that the energy decreases in one place (the person) and increases at other places (the sled and the snow).

Comment: @md2perpe I don't think the appropriate term is "energy flow" as it usually connotes  the movement of energy by means of fluid flow. Rather the appropriate term is "energy transfer".  The string enables the transfer of energy to the sled, since obviously if the string were not there, no energy would be transferred to the sled. The important point is the string does not "supply" energy to the sled. If anything, it absorbs and dissipates energy supplied by the man.

Comment: So there is no continuity equation for energy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Energy_and_heat

Comment: @md2perpe Sorry, but I don't see how the continuity equation has anything to do with this.

Comment: Energy is conserved. The continuity equation is one way to formalize this. Integrating over a region in space, the equation gives that the decrease of energy inside the region equals the flow of energy out through the boundary of the region. Take a region containing the man, but not the sled. The energy inside the region decreases so there must be an energy flow out through the boundary. Isn't that flow where the string is, i.e. we have a flow along or in the string?

Comment: @md2perpe Look, call it energy “flow” if you want. I prefer energy “transfer”. I have a thermodynamics perspective of how energy crosses a boundary between a system and its surroundings. For a closed system, where there is no mass flow across the boundary  that carries energy with it, we normally talk about energy transfer in the form of boundary work or heat.

Comment: For an open system, where there is a flow of fluid across the boundary, we normally talk about “flow”, in particular, “steady flow” conditions where energy literally flows into and out of a control volume along with mass.

Comment: To me the rope is more analogous to, say, the shaft of a piston in a closed system that enables energy transfer across a closed boundary, where the man is the “surroundings” doing work on the sled which is the “system” giving the system (kinetic) energy. No mass “flows” across the boundary. In any case, whether we talk about “flow” or “transfer, energy is conserved.

I think this is becoming more a matter of semantics  than physics. Hope you get the answer you’re looking for.